# How do I keep a value after onchange event is executed on an html form?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Under VENDOR, when "Other" is selected, javascript inserts a row with input to type vendor name and the value is stored as "other_vendor". When the form is submitted I get "Undefined index: other_vendor."  How can I retain this value when its submitted?

```
<?php
    $vendor = $_POST['vendor'];

    if($vendor == "Other") {
        $other_vendor = $_POST['other_vendor'];
    }
?>


<htmL>

  <script type="text/javascript">
             function changeFunc() {
                    var vendor = document.getElementById("selectBox").value;

                    if(vendor == "Other")
                       document.getElementById("row").innerHTML = "<td class='label2'> SPECIFY: </td> <td class='data'> <input type='text' name='other_vendor' <td> </tr>";
                    else
                        document.getElementById("row").innerHTML = "";
    }
  </script>


<table>
  <form action='' method='POST' >
    <tr>
        <td class="label"> VENDOR: </td>
        <td class="data"> 
            <select name="vendor" id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();" > 
                <option value=""> Select </option>
                <option value="CDWG"> CDWG </option>
                <option value="Other"> Other </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row"></tr>

  </form>
</table>
```

Comment: It seems you have broken HTML there. `<input type='text' name='other_vendor' <td>` should be `<input type='text' name='other_vendor' /></td>`

Comment: I corrected it, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Also the last `</tr>` shouldn't be there, since this code will be set as innerHTML in a <tr> tag.

Comment: I saw that and removed it, but still no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue in your code is that you cannot have a form inside `<table>` unless the whole from is inside once cell `<td>`, better option for you would be to wrap table with form like this

```
<form action='' method='POST' >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"> VENDOR: </td>
            <td class="data"> 
                <select name="vendor" id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();" > 
                    <option value=""> Select </option>
                    <option value="CDWG"> CDWG </option>
                    <option value="Other"> Other </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row"></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: That was it.  Thank you for your help.